# Route only loads on page refresh - Ember JS

Tags: ember.js

I am currently learning Ember and I am making a simple app, but I have encountered a strange problem.  I have a route setup and it only pulls the data when I reload the page.  Here is my code:

```
// Start Ember application
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

// Router paths
App.Router.map(function () {

    // Homepage
    this.resource('index', { path: '/' });

    // Book view
    this.resource('book', { path: '/book/:id/:version' });

});

// Homepage route
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        // Get all the books
        return Ember.$.getJSON('/books');
    }
});


// Single book view
App.BookRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        // Get a single book
        return Ember.$.getJSON('/book?id=' + params.id + '&version=' + params.version);
    }
});
```

When I go to /#/book/1/1 by clicking from the homepage, the page is blank.  When I just refresh the page when I'm on there it loads the data and everything works.

Why is this?  What can I do to make it work when the user clicks from the homepage?

Comment: if you already have all the books in the Index route, why are you doing a request for each single book in the BookRoute ?. Btw, take a look here http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/. There's a text: Note: A route with a dynamic segment will only have its model hook called when it is entered via the URL. If the route is entered through a transition (e.g. when using the link-to Handlebars helper), then a model context is already provided and the hook is not executed. Routes without dynamic segments will always execute the model hook.

Comment: I don't know if that's your case, are you using a link-to to transition to the Book ? if so, that's why the page is empty, the model hook id not executed, because you already have the model. And it is executed when you refresh the page because in that case you're entering directly in the url.

Comment: I am using link-to.The JSON would be very large if I were to load all the details of the book on the homepage.  The homepage is just a list of the books then when the user clicks one I want to load the specific details for that book.

Comment: unfortunately that's what the documentation says, if you use it with a link-to, the model hook is not executed. Let's see how other people is doing it.

Comment: I understand.  I need to do this correctly.

Comment: Hello again, I was just reading the Ember docs, and your question came to my mind. I was reading this http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/ if you see, you can pass only the id in the link-to helper, that way, Ember will always execute the model hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions.  I figured it out with this code here:

```
App.BookRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller,model) {
        // Get a single book
        Ember.$.getJSON('/book?id=' + model.id + '&version=' + model.version,
            function (data) {
                controller.set('model',data);
            });
    }
});
```

I used setupController instead of model.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass a model in link-to. paste your template code to check how you are creating links. check this for more info http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/

Answer (score 0):

If you use link-to helper you must not set context model in this one... you simply need to set an id,

```
{{#each book in books}}
  {{#link-to "book" book.id}}{{book.name}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

and the model of the next route will be request.

Answer (score -1):

The Ember `link-to` helper doesn't execute the `model` callback. I've dealt with a situation very much like this recently, and here's how I solved it:

```
// In the index template
{{#each book in model}}
  {{#link-to 'book' book}}{{book.name}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

When you click on the link, you'll get a blank page like you are now, because the `BookRoute` model callback isn't fired. *However*, the `BookController#init` function *will* be fired. You can use this to go and grab the rest of the details about the book there.

```
App.BookController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();

    // Replace doesNotHaveAllInfo with your check
    if (doesNotHaveAllInfo) {
      this.set('model', Ember.$.getJSON('/book?id=' + this.get('model.id') + '&version=' +  this.get('model.version')));
    }
  },
});
```

This way, if the book is loaded through `link-to`, the new details will be fetched. Note that this will require that the books loaded on the `index` route contain at least `id` and `version`.

Alternatively, if you refresh the page, the `model` callback will occur, and your `doesNotHaveAllInfo` check will return false. Whether you click on a `link-to` or refresh the page, you should see your data.

I'd also recommend abstracting the `Ember.$.getJSON` code into a reusable method, perhaps on the model, like this:

```
App.Book.reopenClass({
  find: function(id, version) {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('/book?id=' + id + '&version=' +  version);
  }
});
```

You can then use `App.Book.find()` to return your model in both your route and your `BookController`.

Comment: When you say "Replace doesNotHaveAllInfo with your check", what am I checking?

Comment: You would check your model to see if it had the extra details you want to display on this page. For example: `if (this.get('model.details') == undefined)`