# Ember route loading template only after page refresh

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a simple application with route named addon which has static template.

When I navigate to it by {{link-to}}, page get blank but when I refresh same page template is getting loaded properly.

Same issue is at [Route only loads on page refresh - Ember JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167000/route-only-loads-on-page-refresh-ember-js) but my scenario is different.

router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.mount('ember-engine-addon-demo', {as: 'routable'});
    /*this is only for addon components demo*/
    this.route('addon');
});

export default Router;
```

routes->addon.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

templates->index.hbs

```
{{#link-to 'routable'}}Click here to see routable engine in action{{/link-to}}
<br><br>
<!--this is only for addon components demo-->
{{#link-to 'addon'}}Click here to see ember addon in action{{/link-to}}
```

templates->application.hbs

```
<h2 id="title">This echo is from host app at app/templates/application.hbs</h2>
<!-- load from engine and engine addon -->
{{outlet}}
```

templates->addon.hbs

```
<!--this is only for addon components demo-->
<div style="padding-left:20px; color:green">This echo is from /app/templates/addon.hbs </div>
<div style="padding-left:50px; padding-top:20px; color:red">{{ember-engine-addon-demo}}</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you check the console(brower console) output when you use {{link-to}} redirection?

Comment: it shows nothing. Added a screen shot of console.

Comment: Check what route is recognized by the ember inspector.